# how to do merge dataframe by index

Tags: python

I have 2 DF as below:

```
df.head()

                              GDP   GDP per capita  Access to electricity   Population  kt CO2
country            year                 
Australia          2018     1.428530e+12    57180.779400    100.000000  24982688    386620
Bhutan             2018     2.446866e+09    3243.477437     99.968773   754396      1380
Germany            2018     3.975347e+12    47950.180814    100.000000  82905782    709540
France             2018     2.789594e+12    41572.485010    100.000000  67101930    309960
Indonesia          2018     1.042272e+12    3893.859578     98.510000   267670549   583110
India              2018     2.701112e+12    1996.915087     95.193298   1352642283  2434520
Japan              2018     5.036892e+12    39808.168561    100.000000  126529100   1106150
Korea, Rep.        2018     1.724846e+12    33422.944210    100.000000  51606633    630870
Netherlands        2018     9.135971e+11    53018.629356    100.000000  17231624    151170
Nepal              2018     3.311153e+10    1178.525932     93.920000   28095712    12030
Russian Federation 2018     1.657329e+12    11287.355278    100.000000  144477859   1607550
Vietnam            2018     2.452137e+11    2566.447487     100.000000  95545959    257860

df_temp = pd.DataFrame({'countries':['Australia','Vietnam','Netherlands','Nepal']})
df_temp[['CO2','Population']]=''
df_temp

    CO2      Population
countries       
Australia       
Vietnam     
Netherlands     
Nepal
```

then I map to get population like below :

```
df_temp['Population']= df_temp.index.map(df['Population'])
```

however, I got the column 'Population' is NAN values:
expected output is below:

```
               CO2           Population
countries                    
Australia                    24982688  
Vietnam                      95545959
Netherlands                  17231624
Nepal                        28095712
```

could you please help assist ? I thought the issue is index of df is not the same format with df_temp , tried to print

```
df.index[1]  
('Bhutan', '2018')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if what you want is a subset of your original dataframe, just containing Australia, Vietnam, Netherlands, and Nepal, you can do this using subsetting, without needing to create a second dataframe first, and without using `merge` (expanded into three lines for readability):

```py
countries = ['Australia','Vietnam','Netherlands','Nepal']
columns = ['country','CO2', 'Population']
subset = df[df['country'].isin(countries)][columns]
```

Just change the order of things in `columns`, if you want them in a different order.

If you really want to do this using a merge, the command gets rather complicated because you have identically-named columns:

```py
merged = df.loc[:,['country', 'CO2','Population']].merge(df_temp['countries'], left_on='country', right_on='countries')
```

To get the expected output, you need to subset both dataframes, and specify which column to do the merge on for each. But, again, since `df_temp` is just an empty dataframe, there's no reason to do a merge when you can just subset the original.